# xml parsing xpath error using php

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I am attempting to use xpath to run a program and parse out xml data for repricing books.  However, when I run the program I get the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [<a href='simplexmlelement.xpath'>simplexmlelement.xpath</a>]: Invalid expression
```

and

```
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [<a href='simplexmlelement.xpath'>simplexmlelement.xpath</a>]: xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
```

both on line 242 which is the line of $result...:

```
//function to check if child nodes exist for pricing
function xml_child_exists($xml, $childpath)
 {
$result = $xml->xpath($childpath);
 if (isset($result)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

}

This function is run here:

```
// check to see if there are values
        if(xml_child_exists($parsed_xml, $current->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount))
           { 
            $listPrice = $current->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount;
          } else {
            $listPrice = 0;
          }
```

Then I finally am ending up with:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function children() on a non-object in repricemws.php on line 67
```

Line 67 is where the function is being called.

What is wrong with this code and how do I make it so that it will run correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `$current->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount` contain a valid XPath expression?

From the looks of that call chain, you're pulling out a single value, e.g. '5.00' and passing that directly to the xpath query executor. That's not going to work, and produce your error messages.

---

followup:

ok, so `Amount` is a price, so it's something like $5.00 or 5.00, right? That means you're using that exact string as your xpath query, basically doing:

```
$result = $xml->xpath('$5.00');
```

That is **NOT** a valid xpath expression. So $result is NOT a list of matching nodes in the document, it's actually going to be a boolean FALSE.

You then do an isset() on that value. The variable **IS** set (to boolean false), so your function returns **TRUE**.

Comment: Yes, it is a valid XPath expression and it is supposed to pull out a single value.  How should this be written to execute correctly?

Comment: `...->Amount` should return something like `//div` or whatever. What is it returning now?

Comment: Amount is returning the price of the book.  If you mean from the function, it is returning true if there is a price and false if there is none.